# Pandas Dataframe group by hour of week

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a data frame that contains per hour kWh energy consumption (Consumption) for a house (ID), for a duration of a few months e.g:

```
                      ID  Consumption
DateTime                              
2016-07-01 01:00:00  1642     0.703400
2016-07-01 02:00:00  1642     0.724033
2016-07-01 03:00:00  1642     0.747300
2016-07-01 04:00:00  1642     0.830450
2016-07-01 05:00:00  1642     0.704917
2016-07-01 06:00:00  1642     0.708467
2016-07-01 07:00:00  1642     0.806533
2016-07-01 08:00:00  1642     0.774483
2016-07-01 09:00:00  1642     0.724833
2016-07-01 10:00:00  1642     0.721900
2016-07-01 11:00:00  1642     0.729450
2016-07-01 12:00:00  1642     0.757233
2016-07-01 13:00:00  1642     0.744667
```

Here DateTime is the index of type . My objective is to find the mean consumption and variance for each hour across the week i.e. (24*7 = 168 hours)

```
HourOfWeek    Consumption
1             0.703400
2             0.724033
...
168           0.876923
```

I have tried

```
print (df.groupby(df.index.week)['Consumption'].transform('mean'))
```

However this doesn't give the right results, How can this be done in pandas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index.dayofweek * df.index.hour)['Consumption'].transform('mean')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `groupby` with [`dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html) and [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html), but need add `1` because first value is `0` in both. Then aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby((df.index.dayofweek + 1) * (df.index.hour + 1))['Consumption'].mean()
        .rename_axis('HourOfWeek')
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
    HourOfWeek  Consumption
0           10     0.703400
1           15     0.724033
2           20     0.747300
3           25     0.830450
4           30     0.704917
5           35     0.708467
6           40     0.806533
7           45     0.774483
8           50     0.724833
9           55     0.721900
10          60     0.729450
11          65     0.757233
12          70     0.744667
```

Comment: The answer of @fabhof should be correct, while this is indeed wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Even if late: I had a similar issue and I don't think the above answer is correct, it rather should be

```
df.groupby((df.index.dayofweek) * 24 + (df.index.hour)).mean().rename_axis('HourOfWeek')
```

In the above mentioned answer you end up with unwanted combinations since the assigned groups are not unique, e.g. Monday 2pm is grouped together with Tuesday 1 am and so on

Comment: Remember to take into account the daylight saving time changes: there are weeks with 23 and 25 hours in a day. ;) It is normally safer to calculate the time difference from Monday midnight as a variable to group by.

Comment: Pandas `dayofweek` starts at midnight on Monday (0) and goes through Sunday (6) by default ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.1/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html)) so the answer above should comply with your suggestion.